# What makes a browser load content from an http URL even when frontend source has an https URL?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, https, mixed-content

my vue component is loading external content in an iframe

```
<iframe src="https://external-site" />
```

works fine locally, but once I deploy to my https site

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-site' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame
>   'http://external-site'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

network tab shows 2 requests, both have status (cancelled), and both have request url is HTTPS..

Comment: Perhaps `https://external-site` issues a redirect to `http://external-site`? Is one of those requests in your console a 301/302 status code?

Comment: I would expect the network tab to show a 301?

Comment: I think you're gonna have to link us to an example of it.

Comment: sure thing, the actual iframe src is `https://tithe.ly/give?c=1401851`

Comment: @stackoverfloweth An example of the actual issue in practice. Tithe.ly might issue a redirect in certain scenarios and not others, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For general cases like redirecting URLs with no trailing slash to corresponding URLs with trailing slash added, some servers have broken configurations with `http:` hardcoded in the  redirect — even if the server has other configuration that subsequently redirects all `http` URLs to `https`.

For example, the case in the question had a URL `https://tithe.ly/give?c=1401851` (notice the missing trailing slash) that was redirecting to `http://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851` (notice the http, no-https). So that’s where the browser stopped and reported a mixed-content error.

That `http://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851` redirected to `https://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851` (`https`) in this case. So the fix for the problem in the question would be to change the request URL in the source to `https://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851` (with trailing slash included).

If you were to open `https://tithe.ly/give?c=1401851` (no trailing slash) directly in a browser, the chain of redirects described in this answer just happens transparently and so it looks superficially like the original URL is OK. That can leave you baffled about why it doesn’t work.

Also: when you check the Network pane in browser devtools, it’s not going to readily show you the redirect chain, because as noted above, browsers follow redirects transparently — except when the chain has a non-https URL, causing the browser to stop, breaking the chain.

So the general troubleshooting/debugging tip for this kind of problem is: Check the request URL using a command-line HTTP client like `curl`, and step through each of the redirects it reports, looking carefully at the `Location` response-header values; like this:

```
$ curl -i https://tithe.ly/give?c=1401851
…
location: http://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851
…
$ curl -i http://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851
…
Location: https://tithe.ly/give/?c=1401851
```