# Can not figure out insecure content in Mixed Content error

Tags: http, mixed-content

I'm getting a mixed content error

[image]

on my webpage (flutter) but am not sure how to determine the insecure resource. I've gone through the requests on this page with the Network tab on Chrome, and they are all pointing to https.

In the console, I get this error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://yhat.pub/profile/cbb493d3-4a1c-423b-9813-69da377acda6/build_nbs/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.yhat.pub/build/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

But when I look at chrome dev tools, the URL they are stating http://api.yhat.pub/build/ is going over https.

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Trying adding a trailing slash to that URL, wherever you have it in your frontend code — that is, `https://api.yhat.pub/build/` rather than `https://api.yhat.pub/build`. The problem is that the server response for `https://api.yhat.pub/build` is 307 redirect to `http://api.yhat.pub/build/` (http, not https). But if you add the trailing slash, you can avoid that redirect. Details: `$ curl -i https://api.yhat.pub/build
HTTP/2 307
date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 10:12:21 GMT
location: http://api.yhat.pub/build/
server: uvicorn`. And see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926195/441757

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out.